# How can I fetch only a particular part in the line when using regular expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this string:

```
@body = "@JohnM >John Miller_user Howdy! What's up?"
```

I want it to be:

```
@body = "Howdy! What's up?"
```

How can I code `gsub` with a regular expression?

Here are more cases:

Before `gsub` -- (`_user` always comes after Username. and there's always a space between username, and body string):

```
1. `@PaulW >PaulWhite_user Good afternoon`
2. `@Andy >Andy_user Hi!`
3. `@JessicaT >Jessica Turner_user Nooooooooooo`
```

The output that I want:

```
1. `Good afternoon`
2. `Hi!`
3. `Nooooooooooo`
```

I want to use `gsub` only when it matches this case:

```
@*****(space)>*******_user(space)Body string
```

Comment: It should be trivial. Something along the lines of `/_user\s(.*)/`.

Comment: "I want to gsub it only when it matches this case" - so there, you have the rules. Now open up regex tutotial and translate them. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This is rare case but what if `username` contained `_user`? I want to cover that case, too

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: That's the reason why I will need combination of `@`, `>`, and (space) after it

Comment: @Sergio's suggested regex could be used in several ways, one would be with `scan`: `@body.scan(/_user\s(.+)/)[0][0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
yourString.gsub(/(.*(_user ))/,'')
```

**Explanation:**

1. `.*` will match any character (Occuring 0 or more times)
2. `(_user )` will match the exact string `"_user "`
3. Combining 1 and 2, will match `"(anything)_user "` which gets replaced with `""` (nothing aka removed)

==================

If you instead want to get **all parts of the string**, you can do the following:

```
str = "@Andy >Paul_user Hi!"
match = /@(.*) >(.*)_user (.*)/.match(str)
```

Will result in:

```
match[1] => "Andy"
match[2] => "Paul"
match[3] => "Hi!"
```

Comment: Thanks:) Just in case but what if user contained `_user` in his `username`? Something like `@JohnM >John_user_user Howdy! What's up!`

Comment: Still Works even if so :)  Just tested with `"@Andy_user >Andy_user_user Hi!"` and it returns `"Hi!"`

Comment: Thanks so much. You are right!! What if You want the front part? opposite of the body. I mean `@JohnM >John Miller`

Comment: Is there any way to obtain them with $1(front part including `_user`), and $2(the rest of whole string)?

Comment: Yep ~ updating my answer now.  1 sec :D

Comment: Thanks for the greatest answer:)

Comment: No Problem, you can alter the regex a little bit if you want to include the _user in match[2] or maybe include `@` or `>`. :D

Comment: Can't this be simplified to `gsub(/.*_user /,'')`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/@(.*) >(.*)_user (.*)/
```

It includes the @ and greater than character.

Comment: Thanks:) I tried this code `comment.body = comment.body.gsub(/@(.*) >(.*)_user (.*)/)` and show `comment.body` in view. But it returns this output:( `#<Enumerator:0x0000001c271138>`

Comment: In PHP (`preg_match()`) it works. But the answer above is just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

or

```
str.match(/_user (.+)/)[1]

"@PaulW >PaulWhite_user Good afternoon".match(/_user (.+)/)[1]       # => "Good afternoon
"@Andy >Andy_user Hi!".match(/user (.+)/)[1]                         # => "Hi!"
"@JessicaT >Jessica Turner_user Nooooooooooo".match(/_user (.+)/)[1] # => "Nooooooooooo"
```

To see why this works, let's look at the [`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D) object, `m`:

```
 m = "@PaulW >PaulWhite_user Good afternoon".match(/_user (.+)/)
   => #<MatchData "_user Good afternoon" 1:"Good afternoon">
```

By converting this to an array (using [`MatchData#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/MatchData.html#method-i-to_a)):

```
 m.to_a # => ["_user Good afternoon", "Good afternoon"]
```

we see that the string we want is:

```
 m.to_a[1] # => "Good afternoon"
```

but [`MatchData#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D) allows us to obtain that directly:

```
 m[1] # => "Good afternoon"
```

Incidentally, I initially had `str.match(/.*_user (.+)/)[1]`, but then realized `.*` did nothing, so removed it.